# fgoalattain can't recover from NaN values in function derivatives

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm using fgoalattain in Matlab on a function with two obejctives to be minimized. When calculating the derivatives, it may happen that one of these eveluation fails, giving back an NaN.

As far as I know the algorithm should be capable to recover from this situation, and this was also confirmed by some previous experiences with fmincon that uses the same SQP solver.

In this case no retry with different step size is performed, and the optimization process of course stops. Bounds and constraints are fullfilled with margin, so I don't know why he's not re-trying.

Has anyone a clue?

Many thanks in advance,
Giuseppe.